# Dropdown box to insert value to MYSQL db OnChange using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble executing SQL via AJAX when a dropdown box is changed and would like some help if possible.

**Background Info**
I have been tasked with creating a daily calendar that shows all the classes ran at a gym, which at its maximum is 5 x classes of 6 (30) people per hour for 14 hours.I'm no pro and I may have created a convoluted way around this issue, please let me know if i have.

I have managed to create the view which consists of 14 columns of 30 drop down boxes (5 x classes of 6 per hour for 14 hours). Each drop down box polls the db and if an entry resides it will populate the box with the name of the bookinguser. If no booking is found it will create a drop downbox that polls the members table and presents all the members of the gym,  which when changed, will hopefully book that person in. - herein lies my current issue!

Each drop down box's name corresponds to the time, group and headcount which I intend on passing to javascript function and eventually to the SQL statement. Each option's value corresponds with the memberid which will also be passed giving all the information needed to construct the SQL.

The code I have so far

HTML - snipped generated from php loops

```
    <div id="results">
<div id="07" class="column">07:00<br/>
<div id="group1">
<select name="07:00-1-0" onchange="getda(this.value,this)">
    <option value="none">---------------</option>
    <option value="2">John Doe</option>
    <option value="1">Joe Bloggs</option>
</select>
<select name="07:00-1-1" onchange="getda(this.value,this)">
    <option value="none">---------------</option>
    <option value="2">John Doe</option>
    <option value="1">Joe Bloggs</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gym");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
function hyphenate($str) {
return implode("-", str_split($str, 2));
}
function getmembers($time,$group,$iteration)
{
$date=$_GET["date"];

$date=hyphenate($date);
$date = explode('-', $date);
$new_date = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gym");
if ($iteration == 0){
$result = $mysqli->query("select members.memberid, members.firstname, members.lastname from bookings inner join members on bookings.memberid = members.memberid where bookings.date = '$new_date' and time = '$time' and bookings.groupnumber = '$group' order by bookings.bookingid ASC limit 1");
}
else {$result = $mysqli->query("select members.memberid, members.firstname, members.lastname from bookings inner join members on bookings.memberid = members.memberid where bookings.date = '$new_date' and time = '$time' and bookings.groupnumber = '$group' order by bookings.bookingid ASC limit 1,$iteration");
}
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rowcount==$iteration && $iteration == 0)
{
 $result = $mysqli->query("select firstname, lastname,memberid from members order by firstname ASC");


echo '<select name="'.$time.'-'.$group.'-'.$iteration.'" onchange="getda(this.value,this)"><option value="---------------">---------------</option>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($firstname, $lastname);
              $firstname = $row['firstname'];
              $lastname = $row['lastname']; 
              $memberid = $row['memberid'];
              echo '<option value="'.$memberid.'">'.$firstname . ' ' . $lastname .'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
}
else if ($rowcount>=$iteration){
echo '<select name="'.$time.'-'.$group.'-'.$iteration.'" onchange="getda(this.value,this)">';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($firstname, $lastname);
              $firstname = $row['firstname'];
              $lastname = $row['lastname']; 
              $memberid = $row['memberid'];
              echo '<option value="'.$memberid.'">'.$firstname . ' ' . $lastname .'</option><option value="cancel">Cancel</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
}
else{
     $result = $mysqli->query("select firstname, lastname, memberid from members order by firstname ASC");


echo '<select name="'.$time.'-'.$group.'-'.$iteration.'" onchange="getda(this.value,this)"><option value="---------------">---------------</option>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($firstname, $lastname);
              $firstname = $row['firstname'];
              $lastname = $row['lastname']; 
              $memberid = $row['memberid'];
              echo '<option value="'.$memberid.'">'.$firstname . ' ' . $lastname .'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";

 }
}

 ?>
```

JS

```
function getda(id,booking){
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'samefile.php',
 data: {
   get_option:id
    },
 success: function (response) {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=response; 
 }
   });
}
```

samefile.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
   {
inlude 'config/config.php';

$name=$_POST["get_option"];
echo "<SCRIPT>
alert('$name');
</SCRIPT>";

$sql = "insert into bookings (memberid,date,time,groupnumber) values (1,'2016-04-14','09:00',3)";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);



$mysqli->close();


  ?>
```

The console in chrome looks fine (below) but no records are inserted and the php alert doesn't show. I havent passed any of the variable to the SQL as I was first testing that a query executed properly

jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/gym/samefile.php".send @ jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4getda @ cal.php?date=140416:42onchange @ cal.php?date=140416:36ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:535

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look into jQuery's [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/). I think that it would work with something like below for your code. You could also have it call your function that has ajax in it as well

```
    $( ".class" ).change(function() { //can use #id here too
         $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'samefile.php',
         data: {
             get_option:this.value
         },
         success: function (response) {
             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=response; 
         }
         });
   });
```

Comment: I've added the class .dropdown on all drop down boxes and changed to class in the code you provide but i'm still having no luck. I took off the on change parameters too

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems in samefile.php - `include` spelled incorrectly, an extra semicolon, and a missing closing bracket:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
   {
      include 'config/config.php';

      $name = $_POST["get_option"];

      //this should be converted to parameterized queries
      $sql = "insert into bookings (memberid,date,time,groupnumber) values (1,'2016-04-14','09:00',3)";
      $query = mysqli_query($sql); 

      if(is_object($query)){
          echo 'successfully inserted';
      } else {
         echo 'insert failed';
      }

      $mysqli->close();

   } else {
       echo 'no data to process!';
   }

?>
```

Comment: Hello, the rectifications unfortunately didn't solve the problem, would there be a way for me to test that the code in samefile.php is being run, i tried the js alert but nothing happens

Comment: Right, with ajax you can't use an alert as this is all happening behind the scenes. To return data, you just echo it from the php file. I've edited the alert out of my answer. With this code, ajax could return 'no data to process', which means $_POST['get_option'] is not set, 'successfully inserted, or insert failed. Also check that in your html you have an element with id="result". I see one called resultS in the code above, but if you don't have that element in the DOM, you'll see nothing.